# PDF doc displayed in browser in ASP.NET Core MVC app has blank pages

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, mvs

I'm trying to display a PDF doc in the browser, in an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I use an Ajax call to a controller which returns the PDF as a byte array.

**The problem is**, the document that opens in the browser has blank pages.
Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

The controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public IActionResult DisplayDocument(string documentID) 
{
   byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Info\sample1.pdf");
   return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

And the Ajax call...

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("DisplayDocument", "Document")',
   data: { 'documentID': docid },
   method: 'GET',
   responseType: 'arraybuffer', 
   success: function (response, status, xhr) {
      var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url,'_blank');
   },
   error: ...
});
```

I notice the following:
Original PDF file size: 54Kb
Byte array in the controller: 54641 bytes
FileContentResult returned by the controller: 54641 bytes
response.size in Ajax: 52187 bytes
blob.size: 92736 bytes
blob.type: 'application/pdf'

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share with you that the code you are using to set the response type  `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` to handle the response as binary data is not supported by jQuery to manipulate the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object.you are seeing blank which might be because incorrect conversion process when trying to create a Blob from the AJAX response data.

To handle the binary data with jQuery's AJAX you could use `xhrFields` option. Below is the example you could try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#viewPdfBtn").click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("DisplayDocument", "Document")',
             data: { 'documentID': 'dummyId' },
             method: 'GET',
             xhrFields: {
                 responseType: 'blob'
             },
             success: function (blob, status, xhr) {
                 var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                 window.open(url, '_blank');
             },
             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                 console.error("Error occurred while downloading PDF", error);
             }

         });
     });
 });
```

[image]